# Put all images in DIV tags

Tags: javascript, image, html, styling

Theres a way using javascript function to automatically put div tags in all images?

Example:

```
<div class="example"><img src="..."></div>
```

Comment: You want to replace <img/> with <div><img/></div> ?

Comment: What do you mean, div tags in images? <img src="..."><div/></img> ? That is not possible. Or do you mean wrap all images in div tags?

Comment: @Evel you'll have to be much more specific if you want any help.. example or existing code would also help us understand better. If you post comment back, use `@` like I did here to notify us.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: From your last edit sounds like Mathias answer is what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you didn’t ask for a jQuery-specific solution, but if using jQuery is an option, there’s a pretty easy answer — you can use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$('img').wrap('<div class="example" />');
```

This will wrap all images in a `div` with `class="example"`.

Of course, this is possible in plain JavaScript as well; loop through all `img` elements, and for every node, clone it, create a new `div`, append the clone to it, insert the `div` into the DOM before or after the original `img` element, and finally remove the original `img` element from the DOM.

Comment: He asked to put `<div>` tags in images, not the other way around.

Comment: (And, yes, I know this is impossible. See the comments on the question.)

Comment: I trying this code but it isint working, i need to put it in a function?

Comment: @Tomalak: I don’t think he was. The code example he provided seems pretty clear.

Comment: @Evel: It would have to go inside `$(function() { /* code here */ });` to make sure it happens when the DOM is ready. Also, don’t forget to include jQuery :)

Comment: @Mathias: The code example was added after I posted my comment, and still very obviously contradicts with the text wording of his question.